VSCode Snippets: conditional import based on file path
In a snippets extension, for a snippet, I need to set an import statement based on the file path.
Essentially the logic should be:
if ($RELATIVE_FILEPATH.startsWith('/app') {
    // Next.js with app router / RSC
    render 'import {...} from 'react-bricks/rsc'
} else {
    render 'import {...} from 'react-bricks/frontend'
}

Is it possible to have such a conditional?
Thank you!
Matteo

Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question without tags.

You can do that kind of a conditional in vscode snippets.  Try this snippet:
"conditional": {
  "prefix": "cf",
  "body": [
    "$RELATIVE_FILEPATH",                // just to check what this outputs
      "render 'import {...} from 'react-bricks\/${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^(\\app).*/${1:?rsc:frontend}/}'"
  ]
}

^(\\app).* puts the \app into capture group 1 (if it exists).
${1:?rsc:frontend} means if there is a capture group 1, output rsc, else (iff no capture group 1) output frontend.
Note that vscode is probably returning the path separators as \ rather than /.
You don't want any part of the RELATIVE_FILEPATH in your output, so  be sure to match it ALL with ^(\\app).* - you only need to inspect the beginnging which is in capture group 1.

Thank you very much: it works!
Now, I forgot that these files are created in a sibling folder of the /app folder :(
Is there a way to check if a sibling "/app" folder exists?

@MatteoFrana the snippets manipulate text, not workspace queries, you can try HyperSnips, you can add JS to determine the content

In a snippet you won't be able to check if a folder or file exists.  Do you mean you want to check if Relative_FilePath/someFolder exists?  I need a specific example to think about.  There may be another way.
